# Window length in matplotlib's specgram

Tags: fft, python, window-functions, spectrogram

In [the paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1155/S1110865704310024.pdf) about speaker verification I can read that

*Two quantities have
to be set: the length of the window and the shift between two
consecutive windows. For the length of the window, two values are most often used: 20 milliseconds and 30 milliseconds. [...] For the delay, the
value is chosen in order to have an overlap between two consecutive windows; 10 milliseconds is very often used.*

and later

*Once an FFT algorithm has been chosen, the only parameter to fix for the FFT calculation is the number of points for
the calculation itself. This number N is usually a power of 2
which is greater than the number of points in the window,
classically 512.*

However, in the [matplotlib's specgram](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html) I can only see `NFFT` and `noverlap` parameters which, according to the documentation, correspond to the second quotation.

How can I then set the window's length or what is the default value of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the window length either by setting NFFT = window_length_in_seconds * sample_rate, or, for shorter windows than this, by using a window function of length NFFT where a portion of that length is zero padded.

Answer (score 1):

You'd generally do the FFT without zero padding, i.e. window size == FFT length.

Having an FFT larger than the window leads to an interpolation, but doesn't add any information to the signal, and that's only useful in certain cases – maybe the paper presents one such case.

Comment: So it means that by default the window's length is 256 ms in matplotlib's specgram?

Comment: no. The default window length is in *samples*, not in *seconds*!

Comment: So 256 samples over the entire signal? Say, in 10 s signal it would roughly mean that a sample is collected each 40 ms?

Comment: I don't know how your signal is sampled, so your question can't be answered. Stop thinking in times. Start thinking in samples :)